# Movie about a boy who accidentally went back in time and ends up on a battle field

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

The movie was about a boy who accidentally travels back in time. He ends up on a field during a war. He also meets a girl about the same age; I think they were 10-12 years old.

I forget the middle of the movie, but I remember that at the end he went back to his own timeline and searched for her.

He found her and she was very old because time had passed for her, but he was still young because of time travel.

It's not [*Crusade in Jeans*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crusade_in_Jeans_(film)). He ended up during WWI or WWII. I watched it I think 4 or 5 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

I am thinking this movie is [**An Angel For May**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0313202/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)

> One day, Tom (Matthew Beard) finds a stray dog that leads him to a run-down farm. Suddenly, he is transported back to World War II-era Yorkshire, England. There, he meets Sam (Tom Wilkinson), his daughter Alison (Julie Cox), and May (Charlotte Wakefield), a young orphan traumatized by a German bombing raid. May and Tom become friends, as he works to discover a passage back to his own time. But, when Tom learns May is in danger, he races to find a way to save her.

This trailer shows the young boy meeting the older version of the woman later.